# WPF: ValueConverter (IValueConverter) does not work

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, valueconverter

I have a `Window` class, where I have several `TextBlock` elements which should receive a `Background` color by a value of a `Binding` property. The first "Converter binding" works fine and does everything expected. Today I tried to implement another "Converter binding" with another `Converter` used for it, but it does not work:

(I left out the `ConvertBack` methods because they are not necessary here):

```
namespace InsightTool.Gui.Helper {
    [ValueConversion(typeof(double), typeof(Brush))]
    public class AverageExecutionTimeToColorConverter : IValueConverter {
        public object Convert (object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
            double val;
            double.TryParse(value.ToString(), out val);

            if (val >= 10000) {
                return Brushes.Red;
            } else if (val >= 5000) {
                return Brushes.Orange;
            } else {
                return Brushes.Green;
            }
        }
    }

    [ValueConversion(typeof(int), typeof(Brush))]
    public class ThreadsAvailableCountToColorConverter : IValueConverter {
        public object Convert (object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
            int val;
            int.TryParse(value.ToString(), out val);

            if (val < 100) {
                return Brushes.Red;
            } else if (val < 200) {
                return Brushes.Orange;
            } else if (val < 500) {
                return Brushes.Yellow;
            } else {
                return Brushes.Green;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the `Window` class I used both converts as following:

```
<Window ...
    x:Name="Main"
    xmlns:Base="clr-namespace:InsightTool.Gui.Helper">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Base:ThreadsAvailableCountToColorConverter x:Key="ThreadsAvailableCntConverter"/>
        <Base:AverageExecutionTimeToColorConverter x:Key="AvgExecutionTimeConverter"/>     
    </Window.Resources>

    <!-- This one works fine-->
    <TextBlock Width="10" Height="10" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="{Binding ExecutionTimeAverage, Converter={StaticResource AvgExecutionTimeConverter}, ElementName=UCExecutionTimes}"/>

    <!-- This one does not work-->
    <TextBlock Width="10" Height="10" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="{Binding ThreadsAvailableCount, Converter={StaticResource ThreadsAvailableCntConverter}, ElementName=Main}"/>
</Window>
```

Declaration of `DependencyProperties`:

```
public partial class UserControlExecutionTimes : UserControl {
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ExecutionTimeAverageProperty =
             DependencyProperty.Register("ExecutionTimeAverage", typeof(double), typeof(MainWindow), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(double));

    public double ExecutionTimeAverage {
        get { return (double)GetValue(ExecutionTimeAverageProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ExecutionTimeAverageProperty, value); }
    }
}


public partial class MainWindow : Window {
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ThreadsAvailableCountProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ThreadsAvailableCount", typeof(int),
         typeof(MainWindow), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(int));

    public int ThreadsAvailableCount {
        get { return (int)GetValue(ThreadsAvailableCountProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ThreadsAvailableCountProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

Both `DependencyProperties` are set correctly and their values are displayed in the GUI. What do I miss here?

**EDIT:**

I also tested the following:

```
<Window>
    <!-- This one works fine-->
    <TextBlock Width="10" Height="10" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="{Binding ThreadsAvailableCount, Converter={StaticResource AvgExecutionTimeConverter}, ElementName=Main}"/>

    <!-- This one does not work-->
    <TextBlock Width="10" Height="10" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="{Binding ThreadsAvailableCount, Converter={StaticResource ThreadsAvailableCntConverter}, ElementName=Main}"/>
</Window>
```

It seems that there is a problem for the `Binding` to consume the return value of the "new" converter, but I have no clue why.

**EDIT2**

I check the bindings with **Snoop** and the result was the following:

The `background` property of the working converter binding looks like this:
[image: working_background_binding]

But the `background` property of the not working converter binding looks this:
[image: not_working_background_binding]

Another proof that `ThreadsAvailableCount` is set correctly (Binding to a `Textblock`):
[image: content_binding]

It more and more seems to be a mistake in displaying the return value of the `ThreadsAvailableCountToColorConverter`. That is because in Debug mode, it stops at a breakpoint in the `Convert` method of the `ThreadsAvailableCountToColorConverter`. It even reaches`return` in the `Convert` method successfully.

Comment: Have you tried putting a breakpoint in the Convert method of ThreadsAvailableCountToColorConverter to see if it gets called.

Comment: @R.Rusev It is getting called. I tried that already, but the background color of this control just stays white

Comment: Are there any exceptions or binding errors in the output window of the debugger?

Comment: Is it possible for the second TextBlock to not be where you expected it to be or not be on the top. Let's say if you are using a Grid?

Comment: @R.Rusev At least in the Designer it is at the place where it should be. If I replace the Converter binding code with a static background color it works fine and it is at the right place.

Comment: @haindl Thx for that hint. I am checking one binding exception at the moement, but it actually does not affect this binding above.

Comment: Are you sure the second binding is working? Try data bind the same property without the converter to the `Text` of your second `TextBlock` can you see the int value you expected?

Comment: @Bolu Yes it works as expected

Comment: Remove `ValueConversion attribute` and see.

Comment: @AnjumSKhan removing the attribute should have no effect whatsoever. It's intended to show which types are involved and can be used to pass type info to next converter in line.

Comment: @rbr94 There is still some vital information missing: What does the property declaration for `ThreadsAvailableCount` look like? Assuming this property should be an integer, why is it declared as double? This requires unnecessary conversion like in the converter. Print `value.ToString()` to console in the converter to see what value you're getting. Then print the converted value. Then print resulting brush as string. This will tell you if something's off value-wise.

Comment: @ThyArtIsCode I have added the definitions of the `DependencyProperties` to the post. I have debugged the conversion of the values in the converter, it even does this right.

Comment: @ThyArtIsCode I also tested to use the working converter for the not working binding (see edited question). This one works fine, but if I change the converter back to the old one, it does not work. Very strange

Comment: @rbr94 if the converter is indeed producing the correct value, we know it's not the converter. Strange issues like this are usually the result of a logic error. Like user, aeje, suggested, I would make sure the TextBlock is actually visible and not overlapped by anything and double check everything else is the way it should be. Without seeing the whole sample, it'd be hard to tell. But when the console confirms it, never second guess it!

Comment: @ThyArtIsCode It's definitely not an overlaying. If I set a `FallbackValue` it's displayed at the right place. I edited my post above again and provided some information to the binding contents for the different properties.

Comment: @rbr94 Interesting...instead of using `ElementName`, remove it and try setting the data context of the window to itself. Perhaps it is a strange bug? I noticed the non-working converter is bound to the window and the working one is bound to a different control. I also noticed they are both bound to the window in one of your subsequent edits (was that intentional?).

Comment: @rbr94 also, do you get any additional warnings besides what you've mentioned in your question?

Comment: @ThyArtIsCode Yes, you are right, but that's correct in the edit. It should show, that the binding works with the property and the other converter. I also already have set the data context of the window to itself. And it's also correct, that both shown bindings in the original post reference different windows / controls as element name. Also, I get no further warnings or errors in the debug output, if it is that what you mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah! Finally solved this. I had the exact same problem. With a `TextBlock`, with an `IValueConverter` converting *to* a `Brush`.

The binding was working, no errors or output. The value was getting into the `IValueConverter` code, I could debug right through to the return statement then... nothing!

You've done everything right, but you've automatically imported the wrong `Brushes`. I do it all the time with WPF.

replace the using statement:

```
using System.Drawing
```

with:

```
using System.Windows.Media
```

WPF uses `System.Windows.Media.Brushes`, but it's *very* easy to import the almost identical `System.Drawing.Brushes` and not notice. It all looks fine, until WPF gets hold of it and can't actually use it. But it fails 'gracefully' by falling back on the default colour.

Answer (score 0):

I think could be multiple issues look at the 'output window' for binding expression errors. 
1) Ensure that the textbox are rendered in separate areas and are not 
overlapping. 
2) Use relative path to get to the control and use it property in the binding expression

Your convertor looks fine.

Following is my xaml

```
<Window x:Class="StackOverflowBinding.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:stackOverflowBinding="clr-namespace:StackOverflowBinding"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <stackOverflowBinding:ThreadsAvailableCountToColorConverter x:Key="ThreadsAvailableCntConverter"/>
        <stackOverflowBinding:AverageExecutionTimeToColorConverter x:Key="AvgExecutionTimeConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <!--<DatePicker 
        x:Name="newtally" 
        Text="{Binding CustomerLastTally,Mode=TwoWay}"  
        Margin="0 0 0 0" 
        />-->
        <!-- This one works fine-->
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Width="30" Height="30" Text="Break"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"  Width="30" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Text="Break" Background="{Binding ExecutionTimeAverage, Converter={StaticResource AvgExecutionTimeConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"/>

        <!-- This one does not work-->
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"  Width="30" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Break" Background ="{Binding ThreadsAvailableCount, Converter={StaticResource ThreadsAvailableCntConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"/>
    </Grid>

</Window>
```

Following is my code behind

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace StackOverflowBinding
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        // Dependency Property
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ExecutionTimeAverageProperty =
             DependencyProperty.Register("ExecutionTimeAverage", typeof(DateTime),
             typeof(MainWindow), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(DateTime.Now));

        // .NET Property wrapper
        public DateTime ExecutionTimeAverage
        {
            get { return (DateTime)GetValue(ExecutionTimeAverageProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ExecutionTimeAverageProperty, value); }
        }

        // Dependency Property
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ThreadsAvailableCountProperty =
             DependencyProperty.Register("ThreadsAvailableCount", typeof(int),
             typeof(MainWindow), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(40));

        // .NET Property wrapper
        public int ThreadsAvailableCount
        {
            get { return (int)GetValue(ThreadsAvailableCountProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ThreadsAvailableCountProperty, value); }
        }
    }
}
```

Following is my convertor

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace StackOverflowBinding
{

    [ValueConversion(typeof(double), typeof(Brush))]
    public class AverageExecutionTimeToColorConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            double val;
            double.TryParse(value.ToString(), out val);

            if (val >= 10000)
            {
                return Brushes.Red;
            }
            else if (val >= 5000)
            {
                return Brushes.Orange;
            }
            else
            {
                return Brushes.Green;
            }
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    [ValueConversion(typeof(int), typeof(Brush))]
    public class ThreadsAvailableCountToColorConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            int val;
            int.TryParse(value.ToString(), out val);

            if (val < 100)
            {
                return Brushes.Red;
            }
            else if (val < 200)
            {
                return Brushes.Orange;
            }
            else if (val < 500)
            {
                return Brushes.Yellow;
            }
            else
            {
                return Brushes.Green;
            }
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx for your reply, but this does not solve the problem.

Comment: can you share you files or project like i did ?

Comment: What do you mean? I think I shared all necessary code for this question